# Erlang : convert vapid keys PEM files to base 64 String format (applicationServerKey)

Tags: push-notification, openssl, jwt, erlang, vapid

Hi I like to send FCM push notifications from erlang server app.
When user subscribe to FCM notification in browser.  swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe() need a public key (applicationServerKey).

so to get this key I use openssl and I generate two PEM files private and public keys.

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out es_private_key.pem   
openssl ec -in es_private_key.pem -pubout -out es_public_key.pem
```

I know thet you can get private and public keys from  firebase  console. But the provided keys are not in
PEM format and the erlang library that sign JWT [this one](https://github.com/G-Corp/jwerl) use PEM file to sign and verify.

```
{ok, PrivtPem} = file:read_file("path/to/es_private_key.pem"),
Jwt = jwerl:sign([{name, <<"bob">>}], es256, PrivtPem).
```

So from generated private PEM key I can sign JWT but I need the applicationServerKey in base64 String format to add it in headers and also to subscribe user in browser.

I should convert keys in firebase console to PEMs or convert PEMS to firebase keys format.

I spend two days to try to do this with Erlang.

I found haw to do this in Python I need some thing equivalent in erlang.

```
raw_pub = vapid.public_key.public_bytes(
                serialization.Encoding.X962,
                serialization.PublicFormat.UncompressedPoint
            )
        print("Application Server Key = {}\n\n".format(
            b64urlencode(raw_pub)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Afters days I found how to do this en Erlang.

First I used a library called [base64Url](http://%20https://github.com/dvv/base64url) from someone called Vladimir.

Then I used the code used by authors of [JWERL](https://github.com/G-Corp/jwer) and at the end I do base64Url encode of the ECPoint bin content.

Below the erlang code:

```
pem_to_string()->
{ok, key} = file:read_file("/home/keys/es_public_key.pem"),
 [SPKI] = public_key:pem_decode(Key),
  #'SubjectPublicKeyInfo'{algorithm = Der} = SPKI,
  RealSPKI = public_key:der_decode('SubjectPublicKeyInfo', Der),
  #'SubjectPublicKeyInfo'{
     subjectPublicKey = Octets,
     algorithm = #'AlgorithmIdentifier'{ parameters = Params}
    } = RealSPKI,
  ECPoint = #'ECPoint'{point = Octets}, 
{'ECPoint', Bin} = ECPoint,
base64url:encode(Bin).
```

I'm not specialist in cryptographic and curved keys I want only to sign push content because Google want this. So this code Gives me the 64 octets base64 encoded public key . I can use this public key in push FCM.

I hope this is useful for someone.